# How do I make the dash only show installed application without lens?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

when I click the dash icon,I want the dash only show search bar and applications I have installed.Is this possible in any way? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install dconf-tools, then launch and use [Dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/) for making the change permanent

Once dconf-editor is open, use the left panel to navigate to 
`desktop/unity/lenses/applications`

By removing the tick from 
`display-available-apps`
the applications from Software Center will be no longer displayed in the dash.

If you want to show them again, you will have to these steps again and put the tick back. In other words ,you will not be able to enable the Suggestions again by just using the Filter of the dash.